# Проблема при запуске стороннего приложения из php

Tags: pdf, php

Добрый день, уважаемые. Помогите разобраться со следующей ситуацией. Имеется код на php, вызывающий внешнюю программу, установленную на сервере, в данном случае `apache fop`:

```
$filename = rand(1, 100000);
$file = fopen('fop/output/' . $filename . ".fo" , "w");
if(fwrite($file , $text)){
    fclose($file);
    exec('fop fop/output/' . $filename . '.fo fop/output/' . $filename . '.pdf -c fop/myConf.xml');    
}
else{
    echo "Ошибка";
}
```

Результатом выполнения данного кода должен стать файл в формате pdf. Однако на деле всё происходит немного неожиданно. Файл создаётся, но имеет нулевой размер. Параллельно с этим на сервере запускается java процесс, который висит минут 7-10, после завершения работы которого мы с большой долей вероятности получаем желаемый pdf файл (не всегда). Вызванный из командной строки `fop`, генерирует pdf файл в считанные секунды.

Подскажите, что могло стать причиной такого затянутого времени выполнения программы при вызове из php?

Comment: да, ещё, помимо exec(), были попытки вызова через passthru() и system(), ход событий от этого не изменился

Comment: Что за система?

Comment: Если попробовать в том же потоке через pcntl_exec ?

Comment: debian6, в потоке не пробовал, сейчас попробую